# Database connection on a class

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database

I'm working on a project for school where I have to work with asp.net and sql databases.

I'm wondering If I could use this

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionNameWhateverItIs"].ConnectionString);

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("functionName", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter Parameters = command.CreateParameter();

//parameters
//parameters

connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

In many functions with different parameters just by calling this one time only. Like maintaining the user connected all the time on the database.

Is this slowing the user's navigation?

Is it right what I'm trying to do?

Comment: You will have to find / decide on a balance based on what you are doing... I personally, always instantiate a new connection when I need to access the db in my apps... but I will congregate certain functions in the same stack, to use the same connection object if it makes sense to do so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly re-use that same code with different parameters, here's one way of doing that

```
public void RunMyFunction(IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(...))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("functionName", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.Select(x => new SqlParameter(x.Key, x.Value)));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
...
RunMyFunction(
    new Dictionary<string, object>(2)
    {
        { "@param1", "value1" },
        { "@param2", "value2" },
    }
);
RunMyFunction(
    new Dictionary<string, object>(2)
    {
        { "@param1", "value3" },
        { "@param2", "value4" },
    }
);
```

However, "*In many functions with different parameters **just by calling this one time only***", unfortunately, is not possible.

Comment: This is the answer that I was looking for! Unfortunately I can't Vote up your answer because I don't have enough reputation points. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can re-use your db connection.

Keeping the connection open to re-use vs. re establishing the connection every time will depend on your application.

With lots of simultaneous users, it may be a good idea to re-establish a connection every time a db needs to be accessed, as keeping multiple connections open, while not really doing anything, may cause your application to consume more resources than it has to.

If you are doing a lot of heavy db access, it may be a good idea to keep a conneciton open and re-use it...

You will have to find / decide on a balance based on what you are doing... I personally, always instantiate a new connection whenever I need to access the db in my apps... but I will congregate certain functions in the same stack, to use the same connection object if it makes sense to do so...

Comment: Even if I can't +1, you got one from me!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening and closing connection in each function, I prefer only open one connection to database to response each request from user.

You should close the connection at the end of the response, since you never know if the user will have next request.